# get the urn for the aps viewer from the id returned by the relationships api

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

I do want to use the aps viewer to display documents returned by the relationship api with a response like  "id": "urn:adsk.wipemea:dm.lineage:joRZQICXRY6Uxxxxx". The viewer works fine with any document outside the acc buckets/2 leg auth. But with 3 leg and the urn from a doc in acc not. Even with postman the manifest returns just an empty response.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `urn:adsk.wipemea:dm.lineage:...` refers to a *list of versions* of a design in ACC. If you want to load something specific in the viewer, you must get the `urn:adsk.wipemea:fs.file:...?version=...` of the specific version.